# Visibilty of statements in a view related to transaction?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, transactions

i have a question about data visibility in database views.
I use Oracle.
I have a table myscheme.users and a table global.users (myscheme and global are schemes)
There is a view "globalusers" in the global scheme which merges both user tables.

I have a java application that inserts a new user in the myscheme.users table. After that it makes a query for the new user in the globalusers-view to load the newly created user.
As all this happens inside the same transaction. My question is now, why is the newly created user visible in the myscheme.user table but not in the globalusers-view?
When the transaction has been closed, the user is also in the globaluser-view.

My application is running inside a JBoss 5 using hibernate.

The view is defined in that way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_USERACCOUNT AS
    SELECT u.USERACCOUNT_ID,u.USERNAME,u.INITIALS,u.COMMONNAME,u.PASSWORD,'local' AS source
        FROM "USERACCOUNT" u
    UNION
        SELECT u1.USERACCOUNT_ID,u1.USERNAME,u1.INITIALS,u1.COMMONNAME,u1.PASSWORD 'global' AS source
        FROM GLOBAL."USERACCOUNT" u1
```

Comment: maybe will be useful to add the statemets. create table, create table create view as, insert into, select from, select from. And explain what you see/happens.

Comment: you make an insert into useraccount, after this you create a copy in global.useraccount, and after this a select on v_useraccount and you don't see the user added in global?

Comment: No, i make an insert into global.useraccount after after that i make a select on v_useraccount, and the user is not in the result

Comment: probably you make the select in another session, as justin says.

Comment: Well, as is got deeper in the code (it's not mine) i figured out that there is a second entitymanager for working on the global schema.. I'm not deep enough in JBoss, but could it be that there is no transaction over two datasources?

Comment: @martin - If you have two separate DataSources, the problem is almost certainly that the two operations are happening in different database transactions.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `INSERT` into the table and the `SELECT` from the view are, in fact, part of the same database transaction (which necessarily implies that they are executed in the same database session), the newly inserted row would be visible in the view (assuming the row meets whatever criteria the view uses to determine which rows to display).  If the new user is not in the view, that implies that either

1. The `INSERT` and the `SELECT` are not part of the same database transaction, or
2. The `INSERT` is not sufficient to cause the row to be available in the view.  Perhaps there is some other lookup table that is joined in the view that doesn't have the data for the new row when you query the view but the lookup is populated later in the transaction.
3. You have a bug somewhere in your code where the `INSERT` isn't actually happening when you think it is or the query isn't happening after the `INSERT` or the query isn't actually hitting the view you posted.

Based on your latest update, it appears that #1 is almost certainly the problem.  If you have different DataSources, the `INSERT` uses one DataSource, and the `SELECT` uses a second DataSource, the two operations are not happening in the same database transaction.  They may be happening in the same application server transaction-- the application server may well be creating a distributed transaction-- but if it's not the same database transaction, you won't be able to see uncommitted changes.

Comment: See my modifications of the question for view creation.

Comment: You're absolutely right Justin (+1), but could it be that hibernate is doing some unexpected caching?

Comment: @Miguel - Caching is possible though it would seem very unlikely to me that an ORM would not detect a change when the ORM itself was used to persist the change to the database.  It's far more common to have caching problems when some other application updates the data.  Based on the last update that two different DataSource objects are being used, however, I'd wager that the problem is that two different database transactions are being used.

Comment: Don't know Hibernate, but from analogy with Entity Framework and from reading on the web, Hibernate's EnityManager is synonym of DB session, so it should definetely be option #1.

Comment: Miguel and the rest: you were right. The second entityManager caused a second transaction. I created a service which sepparates the two operations. And now its working. thanks alot!